# How to maintain records of virtual money in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, currency

I'm pretty new to PHP use of MySQL and I needed to learn about the Balance System (Virtual Money) to make my website functional so, first of all I got the inserting money system working:

```
 /* MySQL Begin */

$_CONFIG['mysql']['dbhost'] = 'localhost';


$_CONFIG['mysql']['dbuser'] = '********';


$_CONFIG['mysql']['dbpw'] = '*******';


$_CONFIG['mysql']['dbname'] = 'user';


$_CONFIG['mysql']['tbname'] = 'member';


$_CONFIG['mysql']['field_username'] = 'username';


$_CONFIG['TMN']['point_field_name'] = 'balance';

/* Amount received after topup */
$_CONFIG['TMN'][50]['point'] = 50;              
$_CONFIG['TMN'][90]['point'] = 90;              
$_CONFIG['TMN'][150]['point'] = 150;                
$_CONFIG['TMN'][300]['point'] = 300;            
$_CONFIG['TMN'][500]['point'] = 500;            
$_CONFIG['TMN'][1000]['point'] = 1000;          

/* Connecting the topup service */
define('API_PASSKEY', 'NSTPasskey01');
```

And now, I needed to make a shop system which means that it involves checking for user balance and if the balance is enough it triggers the minus function which subtracts user balance from certain amount and runs the command. I needed help in this part, anyone got any good way to do this?

Comment: Far too broad, try to code something yourself first. If you have any specific questions about that code, then come back.

Comment: What is `good way`? What have you tried?

Comment: What are we looking at here? This looks like your connection configuration. Try writing some functions to do simple, testable operations: `getUserBalance(user)`, `moveMoney(user1, user2, amount)`, `reduceBalanceIfAvailable(user, amount, orderNo)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$_uzlang_conflig: @symbLock(3.14)
$_tty = roungR × 2
Set var sbtr = sq(R+uzlang)
If sbtr = bal(y)
Mov ad > bal()
Cre bal = "user" + "account"
Gen random() = auto.block
Block.add = ha(256) to func(D)
Wait for block(bal);
Do loop = sbtr.auto.gen
```